# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith' with ffmpeg and path

Tags: python, ffmpeg, path

I'm trying to cut a video to the length of an mp3 file but every time I run my code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\main.py", line 26, in main
    ev.finalvideo(
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\editvideo.py", line 75, in finalvideo
    video.cut_video_to_mp3_length()
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\editvideo.py", line 42, in cut_video_to_mp3_length
    background = mpe.VideoFileClip(self.backgroundvid)
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt,
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 35, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration,
  File "d:\programmeerstuff\python\reddit tts bot\try 1\venv\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 244, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    is_GIF = filename.endswith('.gif')
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I'm using the following code:

```
class editvideo:
    def __init__(self, audname: str, outname: str, title: str):
        with open("config.toml", "r") as f:
            config = toml.load(f)

        self.background = config["settings"]["background"]
        self.pathbackground = Path("./assets/backgrounds/video/")
        self.backgroundvid = self.pathbackground.joinpath(f"{self.background}")#Path("./assets/backgrounds/video") / f"{self.background}.mp4"
        self.audname = audname
        self.outname = outname
        self.title = title
        self.path = Path(
            f"./assets/temp/{self.title})/"
        )
        self.backgroundvidtot = self.path.joinpath(f"{self.background}")
        self.backgroundvidmp3 = self.path.joinpath("tempbackground")

    def cut_video_to_mp3_length(self) -> None:
        AudioSegment.converter = r"C:\\PATH_Programs\\ffmpeg.exe"
        audio = AudioFileClip(self.audname)
        background = mpe.VideoFileClip(self.backgroundvid)
        print(background.duration)
        print(audio.duration)
        begintime = random.uniform(0, background.duration - audio.duration)
        print(begintime)
        ffmpeg_extract_subclip(
            self.backgroundvid,
            begintime,
            begintime + audio.duration,
            targetname=self.backgroundvidmp3,
        )
        audio.close()
```

it worked for quite some time but then I got an error with the paths in the `__init__` function which made me add the .joinpath function before that it was

```
self.backgroundvidtot = Path(f"./assets/temp/{self.title})"/f"{self.background}.mp4")
```

I always had problems with ffmpeg on my pc so maybe that has to do something with it.

Hopefully someone can help me,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `str(self.backgroundvid)` instead of `self.backgroundvid` when you call ffmpeg?